# Find the limit of $f_{n}(1)$ if $f_{n}(x)=\int^{x}_{0}f_{n-1}(y)\,dy$ for each $n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Consider the sequence $(f_n)$ defined by
>   $$
> f_{0}(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^3}\quad
> f_{n}(x)=\int^{x}_{0}f_{n-1}(y)\;\text{dy},\ n\ge1.$$
>   Find 
>   $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}(1).$$

I computed $f_{1}(x)$, $f_{2}(x)$, $f_{3}(x)$, but I couldn’t get it that way.

Comment: What are $f_1(x), f_2(x),f_3(x)$ equal to?

Comment: $f_{1}(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2(x+1)^2}$, $f_{2}(x)=\frac{1}{2}
   \left(x+\frac{1}{x+1}\right
   )-\frac{1}{2}$, $f_{3}(x)=\frac{1}{4} \left((x-1)^2+2
   \ln (2
   (x+1))\right)+\frac{1}{4}
   (-1-2 \ln (2))$

Comment: the functions until n=10: http://maxima-online.org/index.html#?in=assume_pos%3Atrue%3B%0Af%5B0%5D(x)%3A%3D1%2F(1%2Bx)%5E3%3B%0Af%5Bn%5D(x)%3A%3Dintegrate(f%5Bn-1%5D(y)%2Cy%2C0%2Cx)%3B%0Afor%20p%20in%20makelist(%5Bk%2Cf%5Bk%5D(x)%5D%2Ck%2C0%2C10)%20do%20print(%22f%22%2Cp%5B1%5D%2C%22(x)%3D%22%2Cp%5B2%5D)%3B%0A

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: Show by induction on $n$ that, for every $n\geqslant1$ and every $x$ in $[0,1]$, $$|f_n(x)|\leqslant\|f_0\|_\infty\,\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ and deduce that the desired limit is...

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad0$

*Comment:* Being given a specific function $f_0$ can actually be a distraction.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that, by convexity,
$$ \frac{1}{8}\leq f_0(x) \leq 1-\frac{7x}{8}\tag{1} $$
so, integrating the previous inequality multiple times, we get:
$$ \frac{x^n}{8n!}\leq f_n(x) \leq \frac{x^n}{n!}-\frac{7}{8}\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \tag{2} $$
from which it follows that:
$$ \frac{1}{8n!} \leq f_n(1) \leq \frac{8n+1}{8(n+1)!}. \tag{3} $$

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaking you can transform your integral into
$$f_n(x)=f^{(-n)}(x)=\int_{0}^x\int_{0}^{a_1}\int_0^{a_2}\cdots\int_0^{a_{n-1}}f_0(a_n)da_nda_{n-1}\cdots da_2da_1=\\=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{x} (x-t)^{n-1}\frac{1}{(1+t)^3}$$
by using the [Cauchy formula for repeated integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration),the integral converges for $x=1$ and $\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$ diverges (if I'm not mistaking)